# Colour regions by order they appear in array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using this [git](https://github.com/roblascelles/uk-postcode-map/wiki/Displaying-the-data), I have https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNWzpq

I am want to colour the regions based on the sequence they appear in my array. It is currently colouring regions based on number of occurrences in the source data:

```
var areas=["AB", "AL", "B", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BH", "BL", "BN", "BR", "BS", "BT", "CA", "CB", "CF", "CH", "CM", "CO", "CR", "CT", "CV", "CW", "DA", "DD", "DE", "DG", "DH", "DL", "DN", "DT", "DY", "E", "EC", "EH", "EN", "EX", "FK", "FY", "G", "GL", "GU", "HA", "HD", "HG", "HP", "HR", "HS", "HU", "HX", "IG", "IP", "IV", "KA", "KT", "KW", "KY", "L", "LA", "LD", "LE", "LL", "LN", "LS", "LU", "M", "ME", "MK", "ML", "N", "NE", "NG", "NN", "NP", "NR", "NW", "OL", "OX", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PO", "PR", "RG", "RH", "RM", "S", "SA", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SP", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SW", "SY", "TA", "TD", "TF", "TN", "TQ", "TR", "TS", "TW", "UB", "W", "WA", "WC", "WD", "WF", "WN", "WR", "WS", "WV", "YO", "ZE"];

var areadata={};

_.each(areas, function(a) {
  areadata[a]=a.charCodeAt(0);
});
```

What I want to do is, for example:

```
var areas=["AB", "AL", "B", "BA"];
```

where AB is the darkest and BA is the lightest, and any unlisted remain the default colour.

I have tried

```
_.each(areas, function(a) {
  areadata[areas]=areas.charCodeAt(0);
});
```

and

```
  color.domain(d3.extent(_.toArray(areas)));
```

but I'm not sure how to match the array order to colours

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, all you need is the index of each element:

```
areas.forEach(function(a, i) {
    areadata[a]=i;
});
```

Also, since your colour array goes from the highest colour to the darkest one, you have to reverse either the range or the domain:

```
color.domain(d3.extent(_.toArray(areadata)).reverse());
```

Here is the forked CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/byvjRE